# Show Regular Price (old-price) in Addition to Special Price of Bundle Products

Tags: price, bundled-product, promotions

We apply a special price or a promotion (catalog price rule e.g.) to the bundle or to a containing product.
Is it possible to show regular and special price of a bundle product like in standard simple products?

The price model and price template of bundle products seems to be completely different from standard price model. It looks like we have to duplicate lots of code to achieve this.